# It's possible to track how many people accepted/declined AppTrackingTransparency permission?

Tags: ios, swift, flutter

I have a Flutter application and I've implemented AppTrackingTransparency permission (required for iOS). What I want to know is if it's possible to track how many people accepted/denied the permission.

Comment: You could add an analytics event to your app to record their response.

Comment: But I don't need to ask for AppTrackingTransparency permission before adding analytics events? Am I missing something?

Comment: No. You only need app tracking permission to use the advertising identifier. You can collect anonymous performance and product improvement analytics as long as it is disclosed in your privacy statement.  If your app doesn't contain ads or otherwise make use of the advertising identifier then your don't need to prompt for app tracking transparency